# Trying to make GET request to Mailchimp with CURL & OAuth?

Tags: php, curl, oauth, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

Everything I look at online is showing how to use OAuth & Curl to make a POST request, but I want to make a get request to the Mailchimp API and I'm not getting any response it seems. I've already managed to go through the authentication and get the user's token & api URL. Now I'm just trying to pull in their lists. Here's the CURL code I've got currently:

```
$headers = array(
    "Content-type: application/json",
    "Authorization: OAuth ".$user['mct']
);

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl,array(
    CURLOPT_URL            => "https://".$user['dc'].".api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists",
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "oauth2-draft-v10",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => $headers,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING       => ''
));
$tresp = curl_exec($curl);
$lists = json_decode($tresp,true);

curl_close($curl);
```

Assuming $user['mct'] and $user['dc'] contain the proper values, any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: why do you absolutely want to make a GET request ?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding how to use CURL & OAuth but their API specifically states the /lists endpoint is a GET request

https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/#

Comment: oops i missed the line where you said you want to read the list... you actually need to make a GET query.

Comment: what is the response code and the content returned by the server ?

Comment: What do you mean by make a GET query? I assume you meant like add the query string to the URL but there shouldn't need to be a query string if I'm trying to access all lists, the endpoint should be all I need. 

As far as I can tell it's not even getting a response. When I echo out $tresp it's completely blank, which made me figure I was doing something wrong with the cURL code

Comment: Actually starting to look like those 2 variables I thought had the correct values do not... -_- hate when I make stupid support requests...

Comment: you can also check for CURL errors using [`curl_error()`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.curl-error.php) if the request is sent to the server there must be at least a response code or a CURL error

Comment: Yep got it sending to the server now so I'm able to get the error response. Should be able to figure it out at this point. 

In case anyone ends up googling and finding this, my problem was that the user information I was getting from wordpress' get_results() function was an object and not an array. 

Took me forever to realize because for some reason this part of my plugin is preventing me from using print_r()

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone ends up googling and finding this, my problem was that the user information I was getting from wordpress' get_results() function was an object and not an array. Took me forever to realize because for some reason this part of my plugin is preventing me from using print_r().

Now that it's actually going to the Mailchimp API I'm able to get and debug whatever error they're sending back.